# Mac ports package name search from command line?

Tags: macports

I tried to install gnuchessc with Mac ports, but there's nothing like that.

```
sudo port install gnuchessc
Error: Port gnuchessc not found
Before reporting a bug, first run the command again with the -d flag to get complete output.
```

Actually, it should have been gnuchess not gnuchessc. Is there a way to let Mac Ports teach me that there is gnuchess instead of gnuchessc from command line?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`port search $TERM`

The [MacPorts Guide](http://guide.macports.org/) is really useful for these sorts of things.